# Linux Samba server for Windows roaming profiles?

Tags: samba, samba4, roaming-profile

I have an existing Windows domain using Windows 2016, and I want to set up roaming profiles.  I would like however to use a linux box (CentOS 8 ideally) for the actual fileshare to save a license.

I can see in the samba wiki notes on how to do this (eg https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Roaming_Windows_User_Profiles), but that assumes that the linux file server will be a member of a Samba domain, rather than an existing Windows domain.

I could potentially join the linux box to the Windows domain using realmd, but it seems overcomplex to me and I'd rather keep it simpler if possible.

So, has anyone done this before, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.